# Reading the average value from MySql Database. C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have this codes in my page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    string selectQuery = @"SELECT AVG(odometer_reading),truck_id FROM 
              inspection WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-12-01' AND '2016-06-01' 
              GROUP BY truck_id";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    foreach (DbDataRecord rowData in reader) 
    {
       populateTable(rowData);
    }               
}
private void populateTable (DbDataRecord rowData)
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("AVG(odometer_reading)")).ToString();
    tr.Cells.Add(cell1);// Error
    TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
    cell2.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("truck_id")).ToString();
     tr.Cells.Add(cell2);
     tbl_TruckEfficiency.Rows.Add(tr);
 }
```

I am receiving an error of `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.` What could be the cause of this.

Or

Is there other way to get the `AVG(odometer_reading)` to get it to `cell1.text` disregarding its datatype to avoid the error. Thanks!

Comment: Try giving `AVG(odometer_reading)` an alias name e.g. `AVG(odometer_reading) as AverageRead` and use this alias name to get data

Comment: rowData.GetOrdinal will fetch column position and not the value. Try using GetDecimal or GetDouble after implementing alias as noted by [suprabhat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3513848/suprabhat-biswal)

Comment: my `odometer_reading` has a varchar datatype means it is a string with numerical values so i did this `object value = Convert.ToDouble(rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("AverageOdo"))).ToString();
            cell1.Text = value.ToString();` Same results

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
cell1.Text=rowData["AVG(odometer_reading)"].ToString();
```